# How to get iframe's refreshed src after interacting

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe, grafana

I have an iframe tag that is linked with a Grafana graph, which supports interaction (zoom in/zoom out on x axis by clicking/double clicking on the iframe).

When I open the url of the iframe's src on a new tab I can interact with the graph and see that my browser's url params keeps refreshing with new from/to values (which indicates the range of the graph's x axis). Unfortunately when it is on an iframe I don't see any changes on the 'src' attribute, on any situation. I need the url parameters changes to apply on other graphs being displayed (sync them all).

How can I solve this situation?

My iframe on Angular's component.html:

```
<iframe [src]="url_grafana_primary" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Iframe after being rendered:

```
<iframe _ngcontent-c8="" frameborder="0" height="300" width="100%" src="http://146.250.180.213/grafana/dashboard-solo/script/script_graph.js?scenario_id=rrc_succ_rate&amp;cell_id=ESICAS23B_ESICAS23&amp;refresh=5s&amp;orgId=1&amp;panelId=4&amp;from=1555045266010&amp;to=1555168469864&amp;var-cell_id=ESICAS23B_ESICAS23&amp;var-scenario_id=ESICAS23B_ESICAS23"></iframe>
```

Some screenshots:

- Before changes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioO7V.png
- After changes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1skA.png

You can see that src keep the same value on both situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute of src is not changing, but the `location` object should behaves the same as it behaves when grafana is outside of the iframe.

You have 2 options,

1. if the frame of grafana & its parent are served from the same origin, you can access the location object with `iframe.contentWindow.location.href`.
2. if they are with different origins, you need to communicate between the frame and its parent, you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for that.

check this example: https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html

Comment: Could you please give an example of how I can use the postMessage on Typescript?

Comment: It is not related to Typescript, it is a browser API.
U have examples in MDN.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Ok... so what I understood is that the 'postMessage' mechanism only works if the target url is ready to receive this message, right? If so, as far as I know, I cannot prepare Grafana (iframe's server) to respond this message as I did not develop it. Please, correct me if possible.

Comment: Also, with a random message, I get this error: "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://146.250.180.213') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:4201')."

Comment: If u are not controlling the content of the iframe, you can't `postMessage` to parent, you are correct.

Comment: If the grafana frame in under your controll, and you can serv it under the same domain as of the parent frame, this will allow you to access the location without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the `onload` event, but to get the URL, you will have to store a cookie or `localStorage`.

```js
var firstTimeLoad = true; // Because the function will call on the initial page

function iframeLoad(iframe) {
  if (firstTimeLoad) {
    firstTimeLoad = false;
    return;
  }
  alert("New page load");
}
```

```html
<iframe width="400" height="244" src="https://wooden-utensil.github.io/linkingSite1/" onload="iframeLoad(this)" frameBorder="0"></iframe> <!-- linkingSite1 contains a link (a href) that links to linkingSite2, and vice versa -->
```

Comment: Thank you but the code under 'onload' is not called when the iframe content is refreshed. Tried with `` <iframe [(src)]="url_grafana_primary" onload="alert('GRAPH LOADED')" id="primary_iframe" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0"
                        #primary_iframe></iframe> `` and it didn't work.

Comment: @DenisCandido I right clicked the iframe and clicked "Reload Frame", and the alert box appeared for me. I don't know why it's not appearing for you?

Comment: Grafana iframe works differently. You can interact with it but it doesn't "refresh". It does update its values but do not trigger the common refresh. I don't know how it works and Grafana community doesn't help me too.

Answer (score 0):

In case when you are not the owner of the content in an iframe, you can't do much. The best you can do is to have a loop (setInterval), that will check the value against the last value you have seen.

```html
<iframe #graph></iframe>
```

```ts
@ViewChild('graph', { static: true }) graph!: ElementRef<HTMLIFrameElement>;

private srcWatcher = new Observable(observer => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    observer.next(this.graph && this.graph.nativeElement && this.graph.nativeElement.src);
  }, 10);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
);
```

having observable as this one, you can now react to any changes on it.

**NOTE:** I would also suggest that the observable should run outside of zoneJS if the interval timeout should be low. Otherwise Angular would run global change detection on every interval. By global I mean, that it would check the whole app any all of the subtrees, that uses the default change detection strategy.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work. srcWatcher never triggers.

Comment: @DenisCandido I am sorry then, it is not possible in any way, it is a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the src of the iframe to the same old src. You may need to add a query string variable with random number like timestamp to avoid caching issues.

```js
function refresh(){
  var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe');
  iframe.src = iframe.src;
 }
```

```css
iframe{
width:100%;
height:300px;
}
```

```html
<p>
 <button onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
</p>
<iframe id="myframe" src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```